# Relation between Jacobson radical of an ideal and the jacobson radical of the ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ be a ring with $1$, and $I$ and ideal of $R$. Let $P$ be a prime ideal of $I$. Is it true that $rad(I/P) \subseteq rad(R/P)$? I am really confused if this inclusion is true or not.

Comment: Well what do you want to ask about, the definition or the inclusion?  What is puzzling you about the definition?

Comment: I am confusing about the inclusion. I don’t know how to show this inclusion trough definition, so I don’t know if the inclusion its true. Or maybe I don’t understand the definition.
 Is this inclusion true? I will edit the question.

Comment: Intuitively I would expect it to be false:  it seems like the maximal ideals of $I/P$ would probably be different animals than those of $R/P$.

Comment: Yes, I thought that too. I am studying this article 
 https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82204709.pdf . In Proposition 1 the author says ''... In this quotient the prime radical coincides with the Jacobson radical, which contains J/P. Thus J/P is a lower nil radical ring '' 
I don't know how the author concludes that J/P is a lower nil radical ring. Is it true that if a ring $R/P$ is a Jacobson ring, then for every ring $I/P$ in $R/P$, both radicals coincides in $I/P$?. If so, why? Thank you.

Comment: I take it back: I didn't realize the paper was talking about noncommutative Jacobson rings. Necessarily, we have to use rings without identity. I see that the argument does rely on the step you are talking about.  Perhaps it appears in Jacobson's basic texts discussion the radical?

Comment: I am assuming $R$ noncommutative, but with identity element. I did not see any statement in Jacobson's base texts that guarantee that $J/P$ is a lower nil radical ring, since both radicals coincides in $R/P$. Actually, what is the definition of ''lower nil radical $ring$?''. Do I have to show that $Nil_{*}(J/P) = J/P$ ? If so, I have no clue how to do it.

Comment: I believe that "lower nilradical ring" means the intersection of prime ideals is $\{0\}$ , yes. I think the idea is that $Nil_*(J/P)\subseteq J/P$ always, and by proving that $J(R/P)\supseteq J(J/P)$, you get a contradiction since the left hand side is $\{P/P\}$

Comment: Even if you assume $R$ has identity element, you don't know that $I$ has one, so you still need the definition of Jacobson radical that works for $I$.  I will have to refresh myself on this and see if I can recreate the logic. i have a feeling that it works out.

Comment: Why do you need identity element in $I$?. I think ex 5, pg 68, from T.Y Lam, gives the definition of rad R, when R does not have identity.

Comment: You must be misreading me. I just said you *don't* know $I$ has an identity and you *do* need the definition that works (like Lam's.) I thought in an earlier comment of yours you wondered why we needed the version for rngs in general.